# how to invoke a build on one TFS server from another using workflows

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to invoke 2 builds on "tfs1" server from "tfs2" server using workflows. My goal is to have a single build definition which will abstract the multiple branches used by a team.

Any info on cross TFS server build invocation would be appreciated.

PS: I am using tfs2012.

Comment: Why branch across multiple TFS Servers? Have you considered proxies instead?

Comment: This remote build invocation is a requirement for development of a test infrastructure. Teams working on hybrid clouds have code across multiple branches and servers. This complicates test infra. Using remote invocation i want to build a uber layer that will simplify things.A workflow will build all the dependent projects and return the drop folder share. These shares will then be used by test infra.   No i have not considered proxies. Can you provide any pointers on that?

Comment: Cant you just customize your build template to queue builds on tfs1 and tfs2 and then poll for completion?